# Independence of product sequence of two i.i.d Bernoulli RVs

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, independence

Let $\{X_n : n \ge 1 \}$ and $\{Y_n : n \ge 1 \}$ be two i.i.d Bernoulli random variables with parameters $p_1, p_2$, respectively (where $X_n \perp Y_n$ $\forall n$)

Define $Z_n = X_nY_n$ for $n \ge 1$. I've been able to prove that the distribution of $Z_n$ is still Bernoulli with parameter $p_1p_2$; however, I'm unsure if the sequence $\{Z_n : n \ge 1 \}$ maintains the independence property. I've tried to prove or disprove $P(Z_{n_1} = a \cap Z_{n_2} = b) = P(Z_{n_1} = a)P(Z_{n_2} = b)$ for $n_1 \neq n_2$, but I haven't been able to make a lot of progress.

Comment: $\{X_n\}$ is independent of $\{Y_n\}$, right?

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Yes exactly, the issue is that the independence makes intuitive sense. I want to directly say that the above equality holds, I just don't know how to make it rigorous.

Comment: You go case-by-case to make it rigorous, there are not too many cases to check.

Comment: Ok, maybe you can provide one example?